Smart Contract as Validator Withdrawal Address: Receiving and Redistributing ETH Rewards
Can a smart contract be set as the withdrawal address for an Ethereum validator, receive the validator rewards in ETH, and then redistribute these rewards to the accounts that provided the initial staking funds?

Sure, check Lido and other liquid staking services.

smart contract can receive ether with callback functions so you can receive reward and You can indeed set the withdrawal logic for  different accounts within the contract. example of staking reward you can check this for better understanding
https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/staking-rewards/

